# Automapper throws an error during post request , Error mapping types, C# WEB API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, automapper, webapi

I got Web Api that is based on classes: Company and Employee, I am trying make post request, but when I am doing that in postman I get Automapper Exception. By the way I am trying to add Company along with multiple Employees in one post request.I could not manage to figure it out and I am freaking out. Thank you for your time.

[This is the exception I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwmAg.png)

[I use this class to Map to database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWFLy.png)

[I use this class to map Employees to database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OzunV.png)

[Company class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LaMYG.png)

[Employee Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0Fjy.png)

[Mapping Class which implements MappingProfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsTiH.png)

[Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFEYR.png)

Comment: Look inside that exception, it will tell you exactly what's wrong.

Comment: Hi, welcome to [so]. Some observations on your question: don't use images, it's very difficult to understand what is your problem. Plase read [ask].

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Company class you have

```
public ICollection<Company> Employees { get; set; }
```

It should be a collection of `Employee`. That could explain the exception you get, trying to map EmployeeForCreationDto to Company is impossible for automapper.

Comment: I am such a stupid, I am struggling with this more than 5 days, Thank you, this solved everything.